# Alfresco : Passing Execution Variables to a Custom ListOfValuesConstraint Constrant

Tags: jakarta-ee, alfresco

I'm using `ListOfValuesConstraint` to provide a list of allowed values for a form control that uses `selectmany.ftl` to present a property of the type `d:text`, I need to get these values from an execution variable set in a previous task, is there anyway I can do this ?

Comment: What alfresco version are you on ?

Comment: I'm using Alfresco 5.0, developing using sdk 2.0

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/repository-services/custom-constraint-03262008-1636) may consider a solid lead towards the solution you seek.

I haven't tried this, but it looks doable given the right amount of time/alfresco expertise !

Comment: I've read it just before posting the question,  it didn't really help as my main point is about passing a value from to the custom constraint. Using a DB_based solution would require the constraint to know what process/task the user in performing.